# How do you split one schema.org item across several pages?

Tags: semantic-web, semantic-markup, microdata, schema.org

I have a single page describing an organisation marked up with schema.org data, there are then multiple related pages with review data on.
At the moment these review pages have the same Organisation tag as the main page but this doesn't feel right to me, it seems like there should be one Organisation record for each company.

Does anyone have an experience or guidance on this matter or the best way of marking up review data on related pages?

-- I have thought about using the organisation url parameter on the review pages which points back to the main page but I am concerned this would eventually impact the listing of these review pages.

**Updated with examples**
This is an example of the main organisation page http://www.insidebuzz.co.uk/law/hogan-lovells
And this is one of the sub pages http://www.insidebuzz.co.uk/reviews/hogan-lovells/question/overall-satisfaction

Comment: Could you include an HTML snippet of your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[update 5/17/2013]
I've now found that the way we can link items from one to another is with `itemid="`. [This link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/ExternalEnumerations#Advanced_Example%3a__Using_inline_description_and_.27itemid.27) is to the [WebSchemas/ExternalEnumerations page "Country" example](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/ExternalEnumerations#Advanced_Example%3a__Using_inline_description_and_.27itemid.27). This example shows how this is done. Pay keen attention to the "**itemid**" usage.

NOT THE ANSWER:
Per [HTML - Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html) -- We can use the HTML5 Microdata "itemref" to accomplish your goal.

[example removed for brevity]

I've done this in MVC by placing the `itemscope itemtype="...` in the MVC equivalent of a Master Page and in the View's (child pages) used `itemprop` and `itemref` etc.

NOT THE ANSWER: 
http://schema.org/CollectionPage 
isPartOf = Indicates the collection or gallery to which the item belongs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I hadn't come across itemtype or isPartOf before. Unfortunately neither seem to solve the problem of one item spread across different urls, unless I am reading the document wrong.

Comment: I've added an update to my "Answer" ...please see the 5/17/2013 update.

Comment: Being able to include full urls in the item id field is great, review data can now be linked back to its parent object. Thanks